# CloudRun cold start issue and 429 Rate exceeded error

Tags: docker, performance, google-cloud-run, monorepo, cold-start

We have a nodejs monorepo project with >179 packages where each package may have >30 files. It also contains proxy with routing and several forked processes (as usual). So, when we packed all of this stuff into Docker image and moved it into CloudRun (with min instance = 1, max instance >10, concurrency=1000), users randomly start see the error '429 Rate exceeded'. (As far as we understood from the documentation, it happens when 'max instances' limit is reached by CloudRun and it can not scale our application anymore. Indirect reason of that maybe too long cold start (which is also limited in CloudRun = 10s). We measured our cold start - it was ~20sec.

To identify the issue of cold start we used this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-so-slow
It showed us that each our small module requires ~5ms for 'import' or 'require' modules. So, average calculation may show why do we have so long cold start: 170 packages * 30 files * 5ms > 25s

For monorepo we use pnmpm and each package builds with tsc.

So, the question is how to improve cold start in CloudRun?

Note: Locally, on dev environment on laptops, we do not have issue with cold start, only in CloudRun. So, looks like, this issue is a platform specific issue.

**UPDATED:** the best approach at this moment, for our case, is bundling all project (or partially) into single js file (with help of webpack or esbuild, like [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-build-typescript.html)) + Cloud Run ['cpu boost'](https://www.infoq.com/news/2022/09/google-startup-cpu-boost/) option

Comment: We have found several approaches to fix this issue but not all of them are suitable for all cases:

1) Lazy-loading for modules (-)

This approach should be adapted from the beginning of the application. Otherwise, it will leads to a lot of risky changes. Moreover, you may loose benefits of static analyzer. Because it is hard to make static checks for dynamically loaded modules.

Comment: 2) Big bundled file (-) Probably, this is the best approach(!) for solving this issue. And, we proved it partially (see below 3). Also, I would recommend this approach for non-monorepo projects. It suitable for monorepos too but with some assumptions in our case. The idea is simple - you need to build you project into singe js file with help of some bundler, like webpack, esbuils etc. In the way, like you do it for client web browser application.

Comment: 3) Bundling per package. (+) Suitable for our case, because we were not able to build all of our server-side packages into single file (see 2) due to a lot of strange 3rd party dependencies which we hard to bundle into single file. In some cases, we need to work with native modules and binaries. So, you need to find all of them across monorepository and, somehow, put it near with bundled js file in pnpm environment (with symlinks). See next comment -->

Comment: 3.1) But instead, we found most heavy packages (with help of 'require-so-slow'), and bundle only internals of such packages. So, other packages in the monorepository will use the bundled version of package. But such packages should be suitable for bundling - it should have an entry point (an index file with exports or exports/main field in package.json. Shortly say, all internal of the package, should be exported for public access via entry point (index file).

Answer (score 1):

To improve cold starts in CloudRun. Please try to implement the points below
.
when it comes to applications written in dynamic languages like node.js,etc.
You should be aware of some modules that run initialization code upon importing.
Minimize the number and size of dependencies if you’re using a dynamic language.
Instead of computing things upon startup, compute them lazily. The initialization of global variables always occurs during startup, which increases cold start time. Use lazy initialization for infrequently used objects to defer the time cost and decrease cold start times. For the details you can check the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#perform_lazy_initialization_of_global_variables)
For detailed description you can check [Article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/3-ways-optimize-cloud-run-response-times) and [Document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! According to dependencies, in our case, it is quite hard to optimized them in feasible amount of time without dramatic changes in architecture because it is quite legacy monorepo project with >100 packages. 

The interesting point in the issue with cold start that it doesn't reproduce on local environment, only in CloudRun.

Answer (score 1):

1. Concurrency of 1,000 sounds optimistic. The default is 80, and I sometimes find that I need to lower that number for best performance. I would try setting concurrency back to its default, and remove the max-instances limit.
2. If your container takes a long time to start you may want to check out the new [Container health check](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/healthchecks) feature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Martin! 
1) The idea behind concurrency = 1000, in our case, were according our project background. The project is a quite legacy. Previously, it was deployed as a single instance server. So, it is not a problem for this server to handle up to 1000 concurrent requests. From another side, cloud run automatically decide when to start new instance of Cloud Run in the moment when all other 'hot' instances CPUs rich ~60% (according documentation of Cloud Run). So, in our case, we set concurrency = 1000, and with help of that completely rely on CloudRun scalability algorithm.

Comment: 1) To remove max-instances completely is a little bit dangerous in our case, because we not sure how many connections may handle our database at this moment. It is quite legacy too.

Comment: 2) We use Serverless NEG behinde Google Global Load balancer. And, according to the documentation, it does not support health checks. Instead we use uptime checks https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/introduction

Comment: This article completely explain our problem with the 'cold start' and partially help us to solve it with help of 'boost cpu' option. https://www.infoq.com/news/2022/09/google-startup-cpu-boost/

Answer (score 0):

...this is continuation for comments above...

3.2) Starting point for nodejs bundling can be this webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports =  (env) => {
  return {
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
    node: {
    global: false,
    __filename: false,
    __dirname: false,
  },
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  optimization: {
        minimize: false
    },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          compilerOptions: {
              outDir: env[1].output
          }
        }
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    pathinfo: false,
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
}};
```

package.json

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "4.5.4",
        "ts-loader": "8.0.3",
        "webpack": "4.33.0",
        "webpack-node-externals": "3.0.0"
    }
```

command to start bundling:

```
node_modules/.bin/webpack \
            --config=./webpack.config.js \
            --output-path="./dist" \
            --env=development \
            --env.output="./dist"
```

`env.output` - uses for emitting *.d.ts files

Comment: Also, you can find some advantages in using esbuild instead of webpack. For instance, AWS by default suggest esbuild bundling: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-build-typescript.html